# AJAX not working on Production Server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis

I have developed an ASP.NET 2.0 Application. I have used AJAX Update Panels in it. Every thing worked fine on my development machine, but when I uploaded it to the production server AJAX is not working there. AJAX calls are REFRESHING the Page.

My Production Server is running Windows Server 2012 & IIS 8.

I have searched for this problem on Google & tried to fix it through web.config but it didn't work.

I also tried doing changes in IIS settings but it didn't worked too.

After some diagnosis I found out that on Browser a javascript error (Sys is undefined) is shown on every Page consisting AJAX. When I looked the developer tools of the browser it showed that a file ScriptResource.axd has not been received & hence the error "Sys is undefined" is generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving 404 error with ScriptResource.axd; then you might want to look at the explanation provided at this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/02/27/asp-net-ajax-functionality-not-working-on-the-page-getting-sys-is-undefined.aspx.
It suggest to put proper handler information in web.config file.
hope it helps./.

Comment: That would mean server is aware that it has encountered an error or is otherwise incapable of performing the request. I would suggest that you check this issue by having a minimal line of code, may be a separate application with only one page, with updatepanel, scriptmanager and button and see if that causes the same issue, just to confirm that is it IIS related issue. If yes, then you might want to look at the framework installation done on server. May be reinstalling resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the ajax extension in your production environment.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=883